# ConfigurationProperties Not Working in Spring Boot2

Tags: spring-boot

```
Spring Boot Version 2.1.4 RELEASE
```

I have client jar with a Settings Bean defined as

```
    @ConditionalOnBean(annotation = Some.class)
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service")
    @Data
    public class WebserviceSettings  {
      //bunch of Properties
      private String serviceUrl;
      @PostConstruct
      public void init() { if(serviceUrl==null) throw ValidationException("bla") }
    }

    Another Config Class
    @ConditionalOnBean(annotation = Some.class)
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(WebserviceSettings.class)
    @Configuration
    public class ClientConfig{ 
       @Bean("webserviceSettings")
       public WebserviceSettings webserviceSettings(){
          return new WebserviceSettings();
       }
    }
```

Client jar is added to spring boot rest service.

The JUNIT Test written for the Client jar works fine and loads up the Bean without any validation Exception coming out of the PostConstruct Method.

Test Class written within the client works!

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(classes = { ClientTestBootApplication.class })
    @TestPropertySource(properties="spring.config.location=classpath:application-test.yaml")
```

However, when I am loading the Spring Boot Service - it fails to load the Settings bean with ValidationException thrown from PostConstruct Method.

```
application.yml
 service: 
   url: "bla"
```

It means that when the client is added to services project, it's not loading the property from yaml. How to solve this?

Project Structure

```
spring-boot-restEasy Application
 - src/main/resources/application-DEV.yml
 --client jar A 
 --client jar B
```

Client jar = [Service Call and some Business Logic], 
application-DEV.yml Contains Service Settings of Client Jar like url

```
Exception 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'service-packagName.Settings': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is ValidationException: [url cannot be Null]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1754)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: How does the package name look like? If you are not in the same hierarchie you have to add @ComponentScan with the package name of the client..jar

Comment: I guess that variable name should be simply `url`. Without prefix. As I see in example from here https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Comment: @SimonMartinelli My Spring Boot Application contains @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "client Package" .

Comment: The Spring Boot Service App?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - Updated project Structure

Comment: As @AlexeyUsharovski underlines it, you should rename `serviceUrl` to `url`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already mentioned the service as a prefix in the following annotation on the class WebserviceSettings.java.

`@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service")`,

then no need to add service as a prefix in the variable (`private String serviceUrl;`).

**To correct it:** Change `private String serviceUrl;` to  `private String url;`

Answer (score 0):

in your application.yml, you have :

```
service:
   url: greetings
```

Your config class must look like :

```
    @ConditionalOnBean(annotation = Some.class)
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service")
    @Data
    public class WebserviceSettings  {
      //bunch of Properties
      private String url; // do not need to use service because you've already specified it in the prefix
      @PostConstruct
      public void init() { if(serviceUrl==null) throw ValidationException("bla") }
    }
```